# Arrange univariateTable output by values not by levels

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I am trying to solve the following inconvenience when trying to export a table consisting of factor levels. Here is the code to generate the sample data, and a table from it.

```
data <- c(sample('A',30,replace=TRUE), sample('B',120,replace=TRUE), 
          sample('C',180,replace=TRUE), sample('D',70,replace=TRUE))
library(Publish)
univariateTable(~data)
```

The default output of the `univariateTable` is by levels (From A through D):

```
  Variable Levels      Value
1     data      A   30 (7.5)
2               B 120 (30.0)
3               C 180 (45.0)
4               D  70 (17.5)
```

How can I change this so that the output is based on the value instead? I mean, the first row being the largest number (and percentage) and the last low being the lowest, like this:

```
  Variable Levels      Value
1     data      C 180 (45.0)
2               B 120 (30.0)
3               D  70 (17.5)
4               A   30 (7.5)
```

Comment: Where do you get package `Publish`?

Comment: @Pascal it was installed from `github`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the "Publish" package is the one installed from `github`, we extract the numbers before the `(` using `sub`, `order` it and use it to order the "xlevels" and "summary.totals".

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github("TagTeam/Publish")
library(Publish)
Out <- univariateTable(~data)
i1 <- order(as.numeric(sub('\\s+.*', '', 
            Out$summary.totals$data)), decreasing=TRUE)
Out$xlevels$data <- Out$xlevels$data[i1]
Out$summary.totals$data <- Out$summary.totals$data[i1]
Out
#  Variable Level      Total
#1     data     C 180 (45.0)
#2              B 120 (30.0)
#3              D  70 (17.5)
#4              A   30 (7.5)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- c(sample('A',30,replace=TRUE), sample('B',120,replace=TRUE), 
          sample('C',180,replace=TRUE), sample('D',70,replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks, it works obviousy, but could you explain what `'\\s+.*', ''` is there for?

Comment: @Opsoum It matches one of more white space (`\\s+`) followed by zero or more characters and replace by `''` in the `sub`.  Basically, it removes all the characters starting from the first space character.